# Android Java Application duplicated execution

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to build android application, and I'm having some trouble.

In default activity I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Log.d(LOG_NAME, "Опрос успешно обновлен (#" + loading_trys + ")");
}
```

and after starting my app, the log shows:

```
08-22 14:40:56.098 10857-10857/ru.oprosy D/LOG: Опрос успешно обновлен (#0)
08-22 14:40:56.155 10857-10857/ru.oprosy D/LOG: Опрос успешно обновлен (#0)
```

The problem is in duplicated executions of code. I'm asking for help to determine what may be done wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to change orientation to Landscape?? Is that a requirement??

Answer (score 0):

Acitvity `onCreate` method is called twice because of a configuration change that occurs: orientation change. In that case an Activity is stopped and destroyed, and then recreated (`onCreate` called once again) to build its view for a new configuration of the screen.

To understand this process better, add logs in every lifecycle callback of your Activity, e.g. in `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onStart`, `onStop`, etc. You'll see exactly what happens when you request configuration changes, minimize your screen or close the application.

Read more on [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).